# python distance formula coordinate plane error

Tags: python, pygame, distance

My goal is to make a circle shape out of lines in pygame, using random endpoints around the edge of a circle and a constant starting point (the middle of the circle). So I decided that I would give the pygame.draw.line function: screen, aRandomColor, startingPosition, and endingPosition as arguments.  Ending position is a tuple containing a randomly generated x value, and a helper function will calculate the y value based on the radius of the circle.  My first function calculates the y value like this:

```
import math
import random

def findY(pos1, pos2, distance, bothValues=False):
    p1 =pos1
    p2 = pos2
    x1 = float(p1[0])
    y1 = float(p1[1])
    x2 = float(p2[0])
    d = float(distance)

    y2 = y1 - math.sqrt(d**2 - (x1-x2)**2)
    _y2 = y1 + math.sqrt(d**2 - (x1-x2)**2)
    if bothValues==True:
        return y2, _y2
    else:
        return y2
```

and the line drawer:

```
width = 500
height = 500

def randLine(surface, color=rand, start=rand, end=rand,length=rand):
    if start==rand:
        start = randPos()
    if end==rand:
        end = randPos()
    if color==rand:
        color = randColor()
    if length != rand:

        end_x = float(random.randint(0,width))
        end_pos = (end_x, "y")
        y2=findMissing(start_pos, end_pos,l,bothValues=True)
        a = random.randint(0,1)
        if a==0:
            y2 = float(y2[0])
        else:
            y2 = float(y2[1])
        lst = list(end_pos)
        lst[1] = y2
        end_pos = tuple(lst)
    pygame.draw.line(surface, color, start_pos, end_pos)
```

Then:

```
drawRandLine(screen,start=(200,200),lenght=100)
```

(the other functions that those ones called like randPos aren't the problem). This for some reason generated an error that I diagnosed as the value inside the math.sqrt() was a negative number.  But that can't happen, since every value in there is raised to power of 2, and thats what I'm confused about.  So I changed the value inside math.sqrt() to its absolute value.  This made the function not raise any errors, but the circle drawn looked like this:

[image: wacky inverted circloid]

I know that pygame's coordinate plane's y values upside down, but should that make a difference?

Comment: Those look *suspiciously* like [hyperbolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola)...

Comment: They're the inverse of each other across the x axis, that's why they look curved.

Comment: The value inside `sqrt` in `math.sqrt(d**2 - (x1-x2)**2)` can indeed be a negative number, if `abs(d) < abs(x1-x2)` is true. `d**2 < (x1-x2)**2` would then be true, and `d**2 - (x1-x2)**2 < 0` would also be true.

Comment: oh, so make the random x value <= the length, with the starting point as  orgin. Ok, thanks.

Comment: Possibly- I can't see what's happening inside `randPos()`, but it shouldn't be generating points further away from the `start` than `length`. Note that the distribution of random lines will still be uneven, with more tending to be vertical than horizontal - see my answer for an approach that leads to a uniform distribution of angles.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice that since I drew 500000 lines, but that probably would be a problem.  But I could randomly choose either x or y, and have an even distribution.

Comment: And, randPos should be between, start_pos-length, and start_pos+length, and same with the y values, if I choose that aproach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of getting a a uniform distribution of angles would be to generate a random angle `theta` between `0` and `2 * math.pi`, and use trigonometry to find the co-ordinates of the end point of the line:

```
def drawRandLineTrig(start_pos, length):
    theta = random.rand() * 2 * math.pi
    end_pos = (start_pos[0] + length*math.cos(theta), start_pos[1] + length*math.sin(theta))
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I could Do:

```
def randPos(origin=(0,0), xdis=width, ydis=height):
    randx = random.randint(float(origin[0])-xdis,float(origin[0])+xdis)
    randy = random.randint(float(origin[1])-ydis,float(origin[1])+ydis)
    return (randx, randy)

def drawRandLine(surface, color=random, start_pos=random, end_pos=random,l=random):
    if start_pos==random:
        start_pos = randPos()
    if end_pos==random:
        end_pos = randPos()
    if color==random:
        color = randColor()
    if l != random:
        b = random.randint(0,1)
        l=float(l)
        origin = start_pos
        dis = l
        if b==0:
            end_x = float(random.randint((origin[0]-dis),(origin[0]+dis)))
            end_pos = (end_x, "y")
            y2=findMissing(start_pos, end_pos,l,bothValues=True)
            a = random.randint(0,1)
            if a==0:
                y2 = float(y2[0])
            else:
                y2 = float(y2[1])
            lst = list(end_pos)
            lst[1] = y2
            end_pos = tuple(lst)
        else:
            end_y = float(random.randint((origin[1]-dis),(origin[1]+dis)))
            end_pos = ("x", end_y)
            x2=findMissing(start_pos, end_pos,l,bothValues=True)
            a = random.randint(0,1)
            if a==0:
                x2 = float(x2[0])
            else:
                x2 = float(x2[1])
            lst = list(end_pos)
            lst[0] = x2
            end_pos = tuple(lst)

    pygame.draw.line(surface, color, start_pos, end_pos)
```

Which fixes the sqrt of a negative problem, and places an even distribution of lines by either calculating the x OR the y, and setting their limits to the specified length, to avoid the strange length of some of the lines.

Comment: My suggestion is practically a 1-liner though. Easier to implement, gives uniformly distributed angles, and has much better performance- each of those random numbers takes about 6 times as long as each of the trig functions I added.

Comment: Don't the trig functions in python use taylor series?

Comment: I'm not sure, I doubt it as Python's trig functions are very fast. I quickly used `timeit` to profile the two versions, my two line function creates `end_pos` with uniform angles in about 1/10 the time of yours.

Comment: Ok ill use yours then, but I haven't taken trigonometry yet so ill have to look into it a little.